# Как вызвать диалог выбора папки?

Tags: c#, wpf

OpenFileDialog открывает только файлы а как выбрать папку?

Для WPF ничего не могу найти.

```
void NodeOpenDialog(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Configure open file dialog box
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.FileName = ""; // Default file name
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".xml"; // Default file extension
    dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.xml)|*.xml"; // Filter files by extension

    // Show open file dialog box
    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

    // Process open file dialog box results
    if (result == true)
    {
        // Open document
        string filename = dlg.FileName;

        GLOBALS.settings.name_f_node = filename;
        //
        NodeOpen1();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте `FolderBrowserDialog` класс.

Пример:

```
FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowser = new FolderBrowserDialog();

DialogResult result = folderBrowser.ShowDialog();

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(folderBrowser.SelectedPath))
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowser.SelectedPath);
}
```